# Accessible yes/no radio buttons that show/hide corresponding form fields

Tags: forms, radio-button, accessibility, show-hide

I'm working on a very old site, trying to update it to be accessible for screen reader users.  In particular, I'm trying to figure out the best way to code some radio buttons where the yes/no values conditionally show other form fields.

I have a prototype at: https://jsfiddle.net/vpyx47qr/

Note: It is just a prototype, though the html is *loosely* structured around the real form I'm updating.

Some extra fields should display when the "yes" radio button is checked.  Those fields are not shown when "no" is checked. If you click the radios in the prototype you'll see what I'm trying to do.

The "yes" radio button has `aria-expanded="false"` and `aria-controls="SpouseYesFields"` attributes on it.

The corresponding "yes" form fields are down in `<div id="SpouseYesFields" role="region" aria-labelledby="SpouseYes" class="spouse-fields" hidden>`

```js
$(function() {
  var $radios = $('[name=spouse]');

  $radios.click(function() {
    if (this.value === 'true') {
      $('#SpouseYes').attr('aria-expanded', true);
      $('#SpouseYesFields').attr('hidden', false);
    } else {
      $('#SpouseYes').attr('aria-expanded', false);
      $('#SpouseYesFields').attr('hidden', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>step 5</legend>
    <p>Are you applying with your spouse?</p>

    <ol role="radiogroup" aria-required="true">
      <li>
        <label for="SpouseYes">
          <input id="SpouseYes"
            name="spouse"
            type="radio"
            value="true"
            aria-describedby="error-subscriber-applying-with-spouse"
            
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="SpouseYesFields">
          Yes
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="SpouseNo">
          <input id="SpouseNo" name="spouse" type="radio" value="false" aria-describedby="error-subscriber-applying-with-spouse">
          No
        </label>
      </li>

      <div id="error-subscriber-applying-with-spouse" class="intake-error-message" hidden>
        Please select one.
      </div>

      <!--spouse progressive disclosure-->
      <div id="SpouseYesFields" role="region" aria-labelledby="SpouseYes" class="spouse-fields" hidden>
        <li>
          <label for="label1">some label</label>
          <input id="label1" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="label2">some label2</label>
          <input id="label2" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="label3">some label3</label>
          <input id="label3" type="text">
        </li>
      </div>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The site already uses jquery and I will continue to use that for updating this form.

All I'm doing is toggling the radio button's aria-expanded attribute `aria-expanded="true|false"` and adding or removing a `hidden` attribute on the wrapping div around those extra "yes" fields.  If you inspect these elements in the prototype then click between yes/no you'll see this.

Is this the best way to provide this sort of progressive disclosure function in an accessible manner or is there a better way?

Comment: Three things unrelated to your question: 1/don't link aria-describedby with error messages permanently, as they are always read even if they are hidden. Do it only when there's really an error. This is a misuse of aria-describedby. 2/Remove aria-expanded, as they are ignored on radio buttons anyway, and 3/Prefer the traditional `<label for="someId"></label><input id="someId"/>` rather than `<label><input/></label>`, as it doesn't work well everywhere. At present label2 and label3 inside the additional form section aren't read by Jaws 2023 in Chrome for example.

Comment: @QuentinC 1) I tested this with NVDA (the only thing I have) and it worked fine.  The error messages were only read when errors were actually presented. Are you saying, for example, this wouldn't work in Jaws? 2) Will check that out, I figured it would be useful to provide some sort of expanded/collapsed state as that's the actual behavior that exists. 3) Great to know, I'll update.  Thanks so much for your feedback, I'm definitely not an expert in this.

Comment: @QuentinC I should clarify, I tested the actual app (not my prototype) with NVDA and the error messages worked.  The app actually also has the traditional label for/input id.  The problem with my prototype is it's just that, something quickly built to show what I'm trying to do. It's loosely based on the app code, but it's not the actual app code.  I'm updating a massive form and it's more of a chore to actually bring that over in a clean way...It's always a struggle when providing code here, I tend to always go for a prototype link as it always feel less overwhelming when you look at it.

Comment: No problem. AS you have seen, be careful when you simplify your code. Sometimes, a small change that you feel totally harmless can have a dramatic impact on accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GOV.UK Design System Team published [an update on the accessibility of conditionally revealed questions](https://accessibility.blog.gov.uk/2021/09/21/an-update-on-the-accessibility-of-conditionally-revealed-questions/) a while ago.

On their component page for radios, they give some updated guidelines for [Conditionally revealing a related question](https://design-system.service.gov.uk/components/radios/#conditionally-revealing-a-related-question)

> Keep it simple. If the related question is complicated or has more than one part, show it on the next page in the process instead.

You might consider **separating the form into several pages**, depending on your use case.

What’s also noteworthy on their component, is that the revealed fields come directly after the radio button that reveals them, which makes the relationship more clear.

GOV.UK are tracking further research in the [Radios component issue](https://github.com/alphagov/govuk-design-system-backlog/issues/59)

[`aria-expanded` is actually not intended for `radio`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#radio), so support will be lacking as well. So everything depends on the layout and structure.

#### Don’t simply hide referenced error messages

As *QuentinC* mentions, content referenced via `aria-describedby` is used for a description even if it is hidden.

> *A. Hidden Not Referenced:* If the current node is hidden and is:
>
> 1. Not part of an `aria-labelledby` or `aria-describedby` traversal, where the node directly referenced by that relation was hidden.

— [Accessible Name and Description Computation 1.2](https://w3c.github.io/accname/#comp_hidden_not_referenced)

So you should also remove the reference when hiding the message.

See also [Usable and Accessible Form Validation and Error Recovery](https://webaim.org/techniques/formvalidation/)

#### Use `<fieldset>`

Should you decide to keep everything on the same page, you probably should use `group` instead of `region`, or even better, `<fieldset>` to group the dependent inputs.

[`region` is a `landmark` role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#region), “sufficiently important […] to have it listed in a summary of the page”. This seems exaggerated, especially under the premise that it’s a conditional block of content.

If you reveal these inputs right after the toggle, `role=radiogroup` isn’t pertinent either. You should replace the overall grouping by a `<fieldset>` as well.

Focus in a `radiogroup` MUST be managed, and if the dependent fields are part of the same grouping, you’ll need to <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus them.

#### Provide missing accessible names

A `radiogroup`, `group` and a `form` MUST have an accessible name, which is missing in your example.

When using a screen reader in form mode, users jump directly to the radio button via <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The text before will only be read if it is assigned to a grouping role.

```
<p id="radio-question">Are you applying with your spouse?</p>
<ol role="group" aria-labelledby="radio-question">
```

#### Always bind to data events, not UIEvent

In general, you should avoid binding to user events like `click` in favour of DOM events like `change`. This makes your code more robust against side effects, like other scripts changing the value.

#### Avoid jQuery for simple tasks

If you don’t have a real advantage of using a library for something, you should always resort to vanilla JavaScript.

Because doing so will only harden the dependence on the library. Switching to another library will always get harder, forcing a complete rewrite at some point, without reason.

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name=spouse]'),
  spouseYes = document.getElementById('SpouseYes'),
  spouseYesFields = document.getElementById('SpouseYesFields');

  radios.forEach(r => r.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const target = event.target;

    if (target.value === 'true') {
      target.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
      spouseYesFields.hidden = false;
    } else {
      spouseYes.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
      spouseYesFields.hidden = true;
    }
  }));
```

```html
<form aria-labelledby="form-title">
  <h2 id="form-title">Something form</h2>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Step 5</legend>
    <p id="radio-question">Are you applying with your spouse?</p>

    <ol role="group" aria-labelledby="radio-question">
      <li>
        <label for="SpouseYes">
          <input id="SpouseYes"
            name="spouse"
            type="radio"
            value="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="SpouseYesFields">
          Yes
        </label>
      </li>

      <!--spouse progressive disclosure-->
      <fieldset id="SpouseYesFields" hidden>
        <legend>Information about your spouse</legend>
        <li>
          <label for="label1">some label</label>
          <input id="label1" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="label2">some label2</label>
          <input id="label2" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="label3">some label3</label>
          <input id="label3" type="text">
        </li>
      </fieldset>

      <li>
        <label for="SpouseNo">
          <input id="SpouseNo" name="spouse" type="radio" value="false">
          No
        </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

#### Get a screen reader and test the result

Today, it’s quite easy to get a screen reader. [TalkBack](https://webaim.org/articles/talkback/) is pre-installed on Android phones, [VoiceOver](https://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/mobile) on iOS and macOS, [Narrator](https://webaim.org/articles/narrator/) on Windows.

To test with a more commonly used screen reader, [NVDA](https://webaim.org/articles/nvda/) is the free option.